# jQuery IE doesn't fire load event

Tags: jquery, load, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue when it comes to showing images once they've loaded. The effect I want is to show a loading .gif behind the image and when it's loaded fade it in. The following code works for any images I load in via AJAX, however on page load I'd like the same effect.

```
$(function() {
    $("#products img").hide().bind("load", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Note, this works nicely in all browsers except IE (only tested 9). From what I understand it's not firing the `load` event because either the image is cached or the image has loaded before the event has been binded. I **want** the browser to cache images so adding a date/time stamp to the end of the image src is not really an option.

Is there a way I can say `If the image is already loaded in some form or another, show it. Otherwise hide it and fade it in once it's loaded.` ?

Edit: I tried setting up a fiddle but it didn't really like it. [Here it is anyway if it's helpful](https://jsfiddle.net/R27Dz/1/)

### Edit

If anyone is interested [I've put up a quick js performance test](https://jsperf.com/show-images-after-they-have-loaded) for the two answers.
[image]
<sub>(source: [grabilla.com](http://grabilla.com/0321b-92ca6469-c766-4d84-8109-b07ab1967850.png))</sub>

Comment: doesn't seem to work here (chrome/ff)

Comment: Yeah looks like that jsfiddle suffers from the same issues IE is having.

Comment: also read 'Caveats of the load event when used with images' here http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Just one thing: isn't the first one always fading in image and the second one only once (and this only if image hasn't been loaded yet)?

Comment: Yes, they do both work in slightly different ways. But both solve the fundamental issue of not displaying the image while it's loading (that jittery line by line loading). Maybe I should update the question to reflect that?

Comment: $("#products").find('img') selector will make it 1.5x to 3x faster as it won't use sizzle

Comment: @DavidFregoli, useful link explaining the issues of `.load()`. Worth noting too (as I found out recently) that `.load()` has been [depreciated as of jQuery 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733) - [See the changelog too](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/)

Comment: And you're right @DavidFregoli, updated jsperf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a filter which passes only images which haven't yet been loaded:

```
$("#products img")
  .filter(function(i, img) { return ! img.complete })
  .hide()
  .bind("load", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(800);
  });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R27Dz/3/)

Comment: Awesome. Think I'll use this solution as it seems faster than other answers. [Did a quick jsperf test to compare the two answers](http://jsperf.com/show-images-after-they-have-loaded) and yours seemed much quicker.

Comment: Doh...! Where did you get `img.complete` from? I mean how did you know it? Is there a reference for?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
 $("#products img").one('load.FadeIn', function () {
     $(this).fadeIn(300);
 });

 $("#products img").trigger('load.FadeIn');
```

Either image has already been loaded and fades in or we manually trigger the event.

Comment: Great use of `.one()`. Seems like a great solution and really simple.

Comment: fyi, loved the solution but picked the other answer as the code runs much quicker. Every little helps. Ty still!

Comment: you can still use one instead of bind in the other solution I guess, shouldn't be faster but will use less memory